# How to parse a json to have backslashes to be used in a request for aws lambda

Tags: python, lambda, api-gateway

I'm trying to invoke an AWS lambda via boto3, putting the json with a "body" doesn't work correctly. after expereminting with the Payload manually I found out that the following string works:

`'{\"body\":"{\\\"searchText\\\": \\\"tote\\\", \\\"published\\\": true}"}'`

However, the original json I have looks like this :

`{ "body": { "searchText": "3350961-STXML", "published": true } }`

Assuming I have no control over the lambda itself. How can I make the json look like the first string. Whatever I do with json.dumps or string.replace I end up with extra backslashes or less.

I tried json.dumps on the body with "body", I tried using string.replace.

Both cases I end up with incorrect number of backslashes.

Comment: `data = json.loads('{ "body": { "searchText": "3350961-STXML", "published": true } }'); data['body'] = json.dumps(data['body']); out = json.dumps(data); print(repr(out))`

Comment: Note that your wanted string won't output that way. `jsonString = '{\"body\":"{\\\"searchText\\\": \\\"tote\\\", \\\"published\\\": true}"}'; print(jsonString); print(repr(jsonString))`